# TeX 1.8 - Invalid Syntax

Tags: python, python-3.x, tex

I'm trying to make a tex pdf using python3 package Tex (v1.8).

The main issue is that a Syntax Error is raised in pycharm while using the [example given on the package documentation](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/tex)

```
from tex import latex2pdf

document = ur"""
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
Hello, World!
\end{document}"""
pdf = latex2pdf(document)
```

the error is this:

```
    """
    ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no `ur` prefix for string literals in Python 3. Drop the `u`:

```
document = r"""
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
Hello, World!
\end{document}"""
```

But note that the project has labelled itself as obsolete, and I don't see any specific Python 3 support being listed. I see that the module uses the `unicode` and `xrange` objects, which will raise `NameError` exceptions on Python 3, for example.

Unfortunately, the linked Texcaller project also looks unmaintained and does not support Python 3 either.